# What are the differences between petitions, complaints, and indictments?

Tags: legal-terms

These seem to be ways of bringing actions to a court. How do they differ and compare?

Comment: I don't understand the close vote or the downvote. This question is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are different terms for initiating documents. What one court or jurisdiction calls a petition, another might call an application. "Complaint" may not have a technical meaning in some contexts or jurisdictions, but often it is used to refer to the initiating document at a specialist tribunal. There are other names for initiating documents: notice of civil claim, notice of action, etc.

There is no way to know which terms have a technical meaning and what those meanings are without looking to the rules and practice in a particular jurisdiction.

"Indictment" is an initiating document in a criminal prosecution. But there are also "informations" (generally implying lesser charges).